# Want to only apply CSS to this specific button element

Tags: html, css, selector

I'm trying to apply CSS to this specific button, but it keeps cascading for all the buttons on the page. How do I make the style specific to this one button? I have no preference on what type of selector is used. Please help, I have 0.0 coding knowledge.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      background-color: #A9A9A9;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 130px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    a:hover,
    a:active {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="URL" target="_blank">Buy Here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use id selector

Comment: Add an [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) to your `<a>` element, and then [use that ID in your CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors).

Comment: I would suggest you to follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). It will help you more than us giving you the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

```
  <a href="URL" target="_blank">Buy Here</a>
```

Use it as this:

```
  <a id="buy_button" href="URL" target="_blank">Buy Here</a>
```

Then apply the CSS to that specific id like this:

```
#buy_button{
background-color: gray;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of a time where you can use an [ID selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp). You can do this by adding id="idValue" to your html element and target it with CSS using #idValue. Here's an example of how that'd look:

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #customButton:link,
    #customButton:visited {
      background-color: #A9A9A9;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 130px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #customButton:hover,
    #customButton:active {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="URL" id="customButton" target="_blank">Buy Here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `id` - but there are maybe better ways to handle it.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #myButton:link,
    #myButton:visited {
      background-color: #A9A9A9;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 130px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #myButton:hover,
    #myButton:active {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="myButton" href="URL" target="_blank">Buy Here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```css
a.btn:link,
a.btn:visited {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 130px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.btn:hover,
a.btn:active {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank">Buy Here</a>
<a class="btn" href="URL" target="_blank">Buy Here</a>
```